# MySQL Community server 5.6.26 10.9 download has 10.8 in it?

Tags: mysql, macos

I am trying to get MySQL running on GM of El Capitan. When I go to MySQL downloads for the Community server there are 2 .DMG archives - one for Mac OS X version 10.9 and one for 10.8. However when I download the 10.9 .dmg archive and open it it contains the 10.8 server. If you look at the 2 MD5 hashes for the 2 .DMGs they are the same.

So is there no 10.9 version of MySQL? Is there no difference? I can install it, but when I try and start it it fails on El Capitan.

I just want to make sure I am not missing something given there is no 10.10 and certainly not yet a 10.11 .DMG archive.

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: I have the same errors, starting the server gives "ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/Thomass-MacBook-Pro.local.pid)".  Any other commands give the "2002 tmp/socket" error which I assume is because the server isn't started.

Comment: My inference is the problem I am having is due to SIP in El Capitan. I think I need to build a virtual server or turn OFF the SIP protection.

Comment: I do have to say that it seems strange that the MD5 for the .tar archives are different, yet the .dmg archives share the same MD5.